# How to combine two characters into one character?

Tags: swift, string, unicode, uikit

I am building a text editor app. I want to implement numbers & bullets like apple's notes app. For numbers I am using "1." (number + full stop). Now the problem is when I try to remove "1." using backspace, I will have to press backspace twice because "1." treated as two characters. This problem becomes worse when my list reaches "10." or "100.".

I have been looking into unicode characters. There are unicodes for "1." (\u{2488}), "2." (\u{2489}), but these are upto "20." (\u{249B}) only. I could not find more than that anywhere.

Can you give me a solution or a different approach to solve my problem ?

Thank You !

Comment: I assume it should be attributed string as a storage, so just add your custom attribute around *number* block (which ever size it has) and on user backspace handle that attribute and remove entire block.

Comment: You should configure the backspace by context. Do not use Unicode for that (try to copy text from app, and you see that saved text and representation are different. You should handle separately (and so other formatting will become simpler, like hyperlinks, colours). But Unicode has a lot of documentation on how to handle group of characters (e.g. accented characters, or indian scripts, etc.) where you may have two Unicode characters but one glyph, or the glyphs (and cursor) do not follow a single direction (e.g. written as ABCD -> displayed as ACDB)